# How to debug "The Application is in Break Mode"

Tags: visual-studio

Your app has entered a break state, but no code is currently executing that is supported by the selected debug engine (e.g. only native runtime code is executing).

Basically nothing is wrong. Just running the program or continue means the program run perfectly.

Something often causes this to happen and I have no idea what.

The programs scan multiple exchanges and uses API.

Where exactly it breaks I have no idea.

What kind of bugs can possibly cause this?

This is my debugging option

[image]

Comment: The debugger will make an effort to show source code for the current break location.  But that isn't always possible, especially so when you used Debug > Break All instead of a breakpoint.  Your program might be buried in an operating system call without PDB files to reliably walk the stack.  Debug > Windows > Call Stack can show you.  Debug > Windows > Threads might be necessary to switch away from a worker thread that was started by a library.  Unticking the "Just my code" checkbox in that dialog can be helpful.

Comment: I've had this issue when I've had dependent projects in the same solution targeting different platforms (i.e. x86 vs. x64)